# A complete list of all paramets in a result set

Tags: air

Does anyone have a link(or know) what all comes from calling the getResult() function on an adobe-air sql statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [SQLResult](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/data/SQLResult.html) object comes back. [Details on getResult() here.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/data/SQLStatement.html#getResult()) You'll usually be interested in the "data" property of the SQLResult.

Comment: Are these the same results you would get with the javascript version of getResult?

Comment: It should be the same, yes. Here's the javascript language reference for SQLResult: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/jslr/flash/data/SQLResult.html

Comment: Thanks, these docs are much better than the ones I was working with!